# Are data files required when creating tablespaces in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I want to create a tablespace, do I have to specify the DATAFILE?
Currently, it is written as follows.

`CREATE TABLESPACE OTS1 DATAFILE 'OTS1.dbf';`

If the DATAFILE was not specified, it was expected to be specified as the Oracle default value?, but if the DATAFILE was not specified, the creation of the TABLESPACE itself was impossible.
So I ask you a question. Is DATAFILE a required value?

I am currently using oracle11g

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Oracle Managed Files, then you *must* specify the DATAFILE value.

From the documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7003.htm

> You must specify the DATAFILE or TEMPFILE clause unless you have
> enabled Oracle Managed Files by setting a value for the
> DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST initialization parameter. For Oracle ASM disk
> group files, the parameter must be set to a multiple file creation
> form of Oracle ASM filenames. If this parameter is set, then the
> database creates a system-named 100 MB file in the default file
> destination specified in the parameter. The file has AUTOEXTEND
> enabled and an unlimited maximum size.